# if page URL contains X and for dropdown option = Y change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply some CSS changes to a form page based on a string being present in the URL and a selected drop-down option value containing a certain string.

The drop-down code is:

```
    <select id="fld-44756">
    <option value="X">X</option>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="Z">Z</option>
    </select>
```

To test this I have tried:

```
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("thestringintheurl") > -1 && ("#fld- 
     44756").val() == 'Z') {    
    console.log('it worked!');
   }
```

This gives me the error below which stops the page loading :

```
  Uncaught TypeError: "#fld-44756".val is not a function
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (recccc:695)
  at j (jquery.min.js:2)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
  at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
   at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Could anyone assist?

Comment: If you are trying to use jQuery here, you are missing $ before ("#fld-44756").val(). It should be $("#fld-44756").val(). The $ is a reference to jQuery-object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

val() is a jquery method:

$*("#fld-44756").val()*

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("thestringintheurl") > -1 && $("#fld- 
     44756").val() == 'Z') {    
    console.log('it worked!');
   }
```

Comment: note also that most of the linters will force you to use at least triple equals (===) aside to wrap each condition in parenthesis

Comment: Thanks for this! Works as intended but sadly not on the system I'm trying to implement it on. I think the HTML doesn't exist in the DOM at the time of page load. It's not there when I do view page source either. Good to know the syntax for this though. Sure it'll come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You gotto use `$` if you are using jquery. It should be -

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("thestringintheurl") > -1 && $("#fld-44756").val() == 'Z') {    
    console.log('it worked!');
}
```

Comment: ( before $ is not required